# Temp table (XXX) already exists in session

Tags: sql, database, stored-procedures, informix

I try to fill my temp table but i get the following error :

```
SQL Error (-958) : Temp table (temp_table11) already exists in session.
```

---

```
CREATE TEMP TABLE temp_table11
  ( emp_num int);


SELECT emp_num FROM hrgetd INTO  temp_table11
WHERE( emp_num = v_emp_num AND calc_year = p_calc_year)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are trying to create table again in your select statement, try this

```
CREATE TEMP TABLE temp_table11
  ( emp_num int);

INSERT INTO temp_table11
SELECT emp_num FROM hrgetd
WHERE( emp_num = v_emp_num AND calc_year = p_calc_year)
```

Comment: Great , but when i check after that `IF temp_table11 IS NOT NULL`
I get `temp_table11  not declared`!!

Answer (score 1):

When you use SELECT INTO you no need to declare your table

```
SELECT emp_num FROM hrgetd INTO  temp_table11
WHERE( emp_num = v_emp_num AND calc_year = p_calc_year)
```